# Permanent storage on computer for data accepted from user

Tags: python, store

I have a basic login program which accepts usernames and corresponding passwords from the user. I found that even if we append the data to a list or add to a dictionary, it gets erased as soon as we close the program. What I want is a way to store this data in more permanent way so that I can access it again when I restart the program.

I have tried using text files as a permanent storage space but the program often throws errors. I want to have a more efficient and powerful way to store the data.

Any suggestions are welcome, but I would prefer if they used standard modules, if modules are to be used at all.

Comment: *"I have tried using text files as a database... I want to have a more efficient and powerful way to store the data"* - a database, perhaps?

Comment: Leaving aside the security dangers of storing passwords as plain-text, you might want to sort out the errors when using text files.  You won't get very far in your programming without those skills.  Seriously reconsider if you should be storing those passwords as plain text please!

Comment: what i meant was a permanant storage space. i'll make the edits

Comment: @cdarke it isn't a serious login program i am working upon. Its just something i decided to make for fun

Comment: what kind of errors your the interpreter throws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a `shelve`, which is essentially a keyed pickle.  That has some advantages, in particular you don't need to read in the whole set (although we don't know how many you intend to store).  Here is an example for Python 2:

First create your shelve, for example:

```
import shelve

db = shelve.open('passwd')

db['user1'] = 'password'
db['user2'] = 'mummble'
db['root']  = 'secret'

db.close()
```

Now test it:

```
import shelve
import getpass

db = shelve.open('passwd')

uname = raw_input("Username: ")
passw = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

if uname in db and db[uname] == passw:
    print "Login Sucessful!"
else:
    print "Invalid Username or Password"

db.close()
```

As I said in my comments, this stores passwords as plain text and is a security risk, but that does not appear to be an issue here.  Otherwise, look at the `hashlib` module in the standard library.

The `shelve` can be used as if it was a dictionary, but it actually uses a small basic database (you should see a file called `passwd.db` depending on the OS).  Note I am using `getpass` which is a standard library module specifically for getting passwords.  You could use `raw_input` if you are not bothered about hiding the password.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pickle (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). It will save your list or dict as it is.

Otherwise saving it in a csv format is always a good solution.